# Is it possible to run an SSH server behind an HTTP reverse proxy?

Tags: heroku, ssh, go, proxy

I am working on an application where the primary interface is via SSH rather than HTTP. More specifically, I am using [Go's SSH library](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh). What I am wondering is if there is a way to deploy to Heroku and have SSH access in some reliable way.

The constraints (if I understand Heroku correctly) are that the application must listen on some port, which is behind some sort of reverse HTTP proxy and accessible only with the correct domain name (i.e. VHOSTs). I would also prefer a solution that can run in a single dyno.

The objective is to be able to run  `ssh mycoolapp.herokuapp.com` (specifying other options as necessary) and be able to make a connection. Please note, however, I'm not trying to get a shell on Heroku, I'm using it for other purposes in the application.

Comment: No. SSH is a different protocol, and a plain ssh client can't use HTTP to communicate with the proxy.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of tunneling over HTTP, like a SOCKS proxy

Comment: You can use a `ProxyCommand` for ssh to tunnel through an http proxy that supports CONNECT, but heroku's proxy doesn't support that. You would need to build a bridge yourself  that accepts an ssh connection, tunnels the data over HTTP to another bridge that connects the stream to the ssh server. But if you're not trying to get a shell (ssh is a "secure shell" after all), you can probably do whatever needs to be done over http without all the overhead.

Comment: The application itself is centered around github and SSH keys, so using SSH is pretty natural.

Comment: Then maybe heroku isn't the best place to host your application?

Comment: That is probably so. I dread being my own sysadmin though :/